# If else statement of popup when click different image button in android

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I am face some problem about the if else statement of the popup window.i want to set when i click different image button and then will pop up different image, but now after i code and test the pop up is no function...

this is my java code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.macarons, container, false);
    ImageButton ma1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ma1);
    ImageButton ma2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ma2);
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    final int width = size.x;
    final int height = size.y;

    positionPopup = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.popup_position);
    if (view.equals(ma1)) {
        ma1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

                ImageView img1 = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.popup_img);
                img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ma_bananacho_popup);
                myPopUp = new PopupWindow(customView);
                myPopUp.setWidth(width - 50);
                myPopUp.setHeight(height - 50);
                myPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                myPopUp.setFocusable(true);
                myPopUp.showAtLocation(positionPopup, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    else if (view.equals(ma2)) {
        ma2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

                ImageView img2 = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.popup_img);
                img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.chocolate);
                myPopUp = new PopupWindow(customView);
                myPopUp.setWidth(width - 50);
                myPopUp.setHeight(height - 50);
                myPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                myPopUp.setFocusable(true);
                myPopUp.showAtLocation(positionPopup, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
```

this is my popup xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/popup_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/popup_position">
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_bananacho"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/ma1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ma2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_blueberry"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_chomint"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_coffee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_greentea"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ma_strawcho"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" />

</GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: add one more else and see. Are you sure you can compare `view` with `ImageButton` by using `equals()` ?

Comment: You are comparing the `view` being the full fragment layout with an specifc component find in this fragment, this can't be true. You don't need those condition, why would you want add click listener on some condition ? You might want to put a condition during each click, but this is not what you have done.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by this `view.equals(ma1)` ?

Comment: thanks for tell me the mistake on the coding.i am take out the if else and then it's work...this is a very stupid mistake of me...sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.popup_img);
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.ma1) {
                        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ma_bananacho_popup);
                    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.ma2) {
                        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.chocolate);
                    }
                    myPopUp = new PopupWindow(customView);
                    myPopUp.setWidth(width - 50);
                    myPopUp.setHeight(height - 50);
                    myPopUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                    myPopUp.setFocusable(true);
                    myPopUp.showAtLocation(positionPopup, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                }
            };
            ma1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            ma2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

1. Create a common clickListener set it to the 2 image views `ma1, ma2`
2. Change the image resource of popup by comparing `viewIds` as below

Answer (score 0):

in java  any overide method will not work in inside if condition because overide method should come directly inside class . so when you r using any overide method you have to put in under the class or direct in class . hare you r using anonymous
class so you have to put if else inside overide onclick  method .for exa.

```
      View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if(condition){
              //for if condition is true

     }else{
      //for if condition is false

                 }
            }
        };
```